# Printing "rotated" numbers

Tags: java

I have been trying to print the output below and I am stuck for quite some time. I have tried out and hopefully someone can give me some hints and i will work it out on my own.

I am supposed to call for the method `printSquare(1, 5);` and I must print out

```
12345
23451
34512
45123
51234
```

This is what I have came out with.

```
public static void printSquare(int min,int max){
    for(int i=min;i<=max;i++){
        for(int x=min;x<=max;x++){
            System.out.print(x);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest taking a smaller, but similar, problem and working it with paper and pencil, thinking through the steps you need to solve it.

Comment: Currently the code prints 12345 on five different lines. Consider how you could start to alter your code to get your desired output. Play around with each of your loops to see where you need to edit your code.

Comment: I know the relationship is +1 for every time.I tried i+1 and x+1 but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Perhaps look at your inner loop and its constraints. Why are you making int x = min and x <= max?

Comment: I am trying not to hardcode because my teacher says it is better not to do so.Hence,i make  x = min and x<=max

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        System.out.print (((i + j) % 5) + 1);
    System.out.println ();
}
```

Comment: Just to explain to the OP in case he doesn't know, the % icon is used to find the remainder of an equation. So in this example, the first loop is (0 + 0) % 5. 0 + 0 = 0. 0 / 5 is 0 with no remainder, add 1 gives you the answer.
If you take the second row of your output (the 23451), when you get to the last number i = 1, j = 4, so 1 + 4 = 5. 5 % 5 = 0 with no remainder, + 1 = 1. That's how it works.

Comment: Hmm.I dont understand why do you plus them together?

Comment: Like how do you derive out this equation?I have some problems visualizing.

Comment: @user2059072: See my comment.

Comment: 12 % 5 = 2 because 12 / 5 = 2, with 2 remainder. The % calculates the remainder. 13 % 2 = 1 because 13 / 2 = 6, with 1 remainder.

Comment: Also to add in, as the inner loop only has one line, it doesn't need braces around it. The inner loop executes on that one line and once it is finished, it executes the System.out.println() before going back to the first loop, incrementing it, executing the inner loop again etc.

Comment: @vikiiii: To be honest I'm not sure. This is how I always learnt to do it at the start of my university course. Our lecturer had us using % on our very first day!

Comment: Hmm.i tried out in the compiler and it seems the output generated is wrong.

Comment: @user2059072: It's compiling fine on my end. Make sure to put it in the printSquare methods and close the braces. What output are you getting?

Comment: Yes.It works fine.Thank you for your help.I will try to look through again and slowly figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, it might help you.

```
public static void printSquare(int min,int max){
  for(int i=min;i<=max;i++){
      int iVal=i;
    for(int x=min;x<=max;x++){

      if(iVal>max){
        System.out.print(iVal-(max-min+1));
      }else{
        System.out.print(iVal);
      }
      iVal++;
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the generic pseudocode design that you should keep in mind:

- Iterate on the bound of `max`.

  - Print your first number set.
  - Iterate through the maximum bounds of an array.

    - If the remainder of `max` and your current position's value is 0, then it is set to `min`.
    - Otherwise, increase the value of your current position by 1.

Here's a rough implementation, involving an array.

```
public void printRotatedNumbers(int[] array, int a, int b) {
    for(int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if(array[j] % b == 0) {
                array[j] = a;
            } else {
                ++array[j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On an array of 10 integer elements, with `a = 1` and `b = 10`, you get:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void print(int min, int max) {
    for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        int val = i;
        do {
            System.out.print(val);
            if (val == max) {
                val = min;
            } else {
                val++;
            }
        } while (val != i);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```